# Does the Reopen queue have review audits?

Tags: support, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

I'm doing reviews in the Reopen queue and I have never encountered a review audit.

Are there any review audits in the Reopen queue as there are in other queues?

Do audits depends on the size of the queue?

**EDIT**:

My 151 reopen queue review was an [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/18550749)

Comment: There are... There's been 179 in the last two days - you just haven't been given one yet - don't worry though statistically you're likely to get one soon.

Comment: Can I see/filter by tests in my review history?

Comment: Not currently - I think there's a feature request for that - but of the last 7 days in the reopen queue you've not had any audits... Which does seem a little odd but then there doesn't appear to be a large amount of audits issued overall anyway for that one.

Comment: You can spot your audits in your review history with this script of mine: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100

Comment: It seems that different queue have different test rate? is it queue size related? or more by chance?

Comment: IIRC it is on average around 1 audit per 50 review tasks. I think that is for all queues but for sure that is the number for the CVQ.

Comment: I got few tests per day in First Posts but non in Reopen queue

Comment: The audit selection criteria differs per queue - along with the queue size and the number of reviewers - there's no hard and fast rule on how often you'll get an audit.

Comment: well, noone has even used the reopen queue enough to get an audit :)